# Subdivision, rounded edges problem

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface, bevel

I'm trying to create a door handle with smooth rounded edges, like this:

[image: Door handle reference]

I'm having a problem when trying to bevel or apply a subdivision surface modifier, mainly that I'm not able to correctly apply loop cuts to sort out the modifier.

Also bevelling the edges both with a modifier and with ctrl+b isnt having the desired effect, sometimes it doesnt even give me the option to bevel.

Here are some pictures of the nasty creases i get across some edges after i apply the subdivision surface modifier and add loop cuts

[image: Screenshots of errors]

Comment: The problem you're having is mainly because you have a lot of N-gons.
You should try keeping the topology in a clean manner by using only quads. You can use triangles as a ultimate last resort.
Also, have you applied the scale and rotation yet? this may cause problems with beveling too.

Comment: There are also internal faces in your model in the part where the curve meets the straight part. Eliminate any non-manifold faces.

Comment: make the base with this base you use extrude to one axis with scale - this make the smooth area.
finally add the last parts: the handle and the hub key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have some duplicate vertices and/or faces in your model. The first thing to do should be to remove your duplicate vertices. In Edit Mode, select the entire mesh by pressing `A`. Then, press `W` and click "Remove Doubles". This should help to clean things up. If this doesn't fix it, make sure that you are using the Bevel Modifier *before* the SubSurf modifier. This will prevent your SubSurf modifier from destroying your topology. Since you have a cylinder, you want the "curved" faces sub-surfed, but not beveled. To do this, set the Bevel Modifier limit method to "Angle" and set the angle to something greater than the angle formed between two of the cylinders sides (probably about 15 degrees). To get a cleaner bevel at sharp corners, set the width method to "Width". To get the curved effect in your reference image, increase the Bevel Segments and Profile. It should look like this:[image]
[image]